# Hazelcast XATransaction with Bitronix Transaction Manager

Tags: java, transactions, hazelcast, xa, bitronix

I'm making some tests with Hazelcast XA Transactions and I'm having trouble when using Bitronix as the Transaction Manager.

I have followed Hazelcast official documentation:

> http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/xatransactions.html

**Libs versions:**

`Hazelcast: 3.5.4`

`Bitronix Transaction Manager: 2.1.4`

`Java: 1.7`

**Code:**

**Test method:**

```
@Test
public void hazelcastBitronixXATransactionTest() throws Exception{
    try{
        doHazelcastXATransactionTest(createInstance("myCluster"));
    }catch(Exception e){
        Assert.fail();
        System.out.println("Other Exception:" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Hazelcast instance creation method:**

```
private HazelcastInstance createInstance(String clusterName){
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "slf4j");

    Config config = new Config();
    config.getGroupConfig().setName(clusterName);
    config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(true);

    TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getTcpIpConfig();
    tcpIpConfig.setEnabled(false);

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

**Do method:**

```
private void doHazelcastXATransactionTest(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) throws Exception{
  BitronixTransactionManager btm = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();
  btm.setTransactionTimeout(60);
  btm.begin();

  HazelcastXAResource xaResource = hazelcastInstance.getXAResource();

  Transaction transaction = btm.getTransaction();
  transaction.enlistResource(xaResource);

  try {
      TransactionContext context = xaResource.getTransactionContext();
      TransactionalMap map = context.getMap("m");
      map.put("key", "value");

      transaction.delistResource(xaResource, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);

      btm.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception do rollback:" + e.getMessage());
      btm.rollback();
  }
}
```

I'm receiving a `BitronixSystemException`, thrown when trying to enlist the XA resource `transaction.enlistResource(xaResource)`.

The complete **stacktrace:**

```
bitronix.tm.internal.BitronixSystemException: unknown XAResource HazelcastXaResource {myCluster}, it does not belong to a registered resource
```

Someone has faced this issue? Any clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Bitronix needs XAResources to be registered before using them.
I've added below line after obtaining the `HazelcastXAResource` and it worked.

`EhCacheXAResourceProducer.registerXAResource(xaResource.getName(), xaResource);`